# Запрос INSERT INTO не передает данные в базу данных

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Я делаю регистрацию на php и при использование INSERT INTO - данные   не передаются в базу данных. В чем может быть проблема?

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
    <input name="login">
    <input name="password" type="password">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['login'])) { $login = $_POST['login']; if ($login == '') { unset($login);} } //заносим введенный пользователем логин в переменную $login, если он пустой, то уничтожаем переменную
    if (isset($_POST['password'])) { $password=$_POST['password']; if ($password =='') { unset($password);} }
    //заносим введенный пользователем пароль в переменную $password, если он пустой, то уничтожаем переменную
 if (empty($login) or empty($password)) //если пользователь не ввел логин или пароль, то выдаем ошибку и останавливаем скрипт
    {
    exit ("Вы ввели не всю информацию, вернитесь назад и заполните все поля!");
    }
    //если логин и пароль введены, то обрабатываем их, чтобы теги и скрипты не работали, мало ли что люди могут ввести
    $login = stripslashes($login);
    $login = htmlspecialchars($login);
 $password = stripslashes($password);
    $password = htmlspecialchars($password);
 //удаляем лишние пробелы
    $login = trim($login);
    $password = trim($password);
 // подключаемся к базе
    include ("bd.php");// файл bd.php должен быть в той же папке, что и все остальные, если это не так, то просто измените путь 
 // проверка на существование пользователя с таким же логином
    
 // если такого нет, то сохраняем данные
 $query = "INSERT INTO test1 SET login='$login',password='$password'"; 
mysqli_query($link, $query);
    if ($result2=='TRUE')
    {
    echo "Вы успешно зарегистрированы! Теперь вы можете зайти на сайт. <a href='index.php'>Главная страница</a>";
    }
 else {
    echo "Ошибка! Вы не зарегистрированы.";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: `insert into test1 VALUES ('$login', '$password')`

Comment: @yW0K5o,пробовал, не помогает

Comment: А какие колонки в таблице `test1`? А Вы пробовали `insert into test1 (login,password) VALUES ('$login', '$password');`

Comment: Также [см](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: @yW0K5o, спасибо за помощь! Я действительно забыл про колонку id. Я добавил ей  autoincrement. Теперь все нормально работает.

Comment: Не так может быть что угодно. Всегда проверяйте результат выполнения mysqli_query и если он возвращает false, то выводите ошибку mysqli::$error что бы понимать что происходит. Или включите какой нибудь подходящий режим протоколирования (mysqli_report). А еще не помешало бы использовать подготовленные запросы (mysqli_prepare) и привязку переменных (bind_param) вместо подстановки переменных в явном виде.

Comment: А ваши stripslashes и htmlspecialchars ни как не помогут. Передайте в пароле `'` и запрос сломается. И в него можно будет подставить много чего интересного, например создать сразу десяток пользователей за раз. И для пароля они вредны. Может я хочу в пароле использовать `/` но его просто удалят ... Только подготовленные запросы способны защитить вас от ошибок на некоторых входных данных и взлома сайта